# A grid cell has both image and text

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there any way to put both an image and text on Ext js 4 grid panel's cell?

Thanks for help.

ck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. But depends of your requirements which way to choose.

1. Use CSS. When you define a column, set the 'tdCls' property:

   ```
   {
       header: 'Image and text column',
       tdCls: 'img-col',
       dataIndex: 'Text'
   }
   ```

   in CSS file:

   ```
   td.img-col  {
       background-image: url(images/pic.png); /*16px*/
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }

   td.img-col .x-grid-cell-inner {
       margin-left: 16px;
   }
   ```
2. Use template column:

   ```
   {
       xtype: 'templatecolumn',
       header: 'Image and text column',
       tpl: [
           '<img src="{ImgPath}"></img>',
           '<div>{Text}</div>'
       ]
   }
   ```

   And your model should have the `ImgPath` property